# What is the simplest working example with routes in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have found several examples with Routes and Angular and sadly none of them worked, including [the "official" guide example](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.directive:ngView) (clicking there gets wrong URL which does not work upon reload).

- Is there any simple working example with correct URL updates that work upon reload?
- Is there any such example with tabs?

---

EDIT.
I've managed to making routes working by removing `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`. 
If enable, it produced corrupted URLs in my browser
(I use Chrome 31.0.1650.63 with Mac OS 10.8.5)

Comment: Link works fine for me, example has routes in `script.js`

Comment: @elclanrs Have you tried to click and reload?

Comment: Tried. Everything works fine for me. Check this site for tutorials https://egghead.io/

Comment: @elclanrs This is the link I get upon clicking: http://docs.angularjs.org/Book/Moby - it does not work. Also I need an example that works locally, not just in-demo on the site.

Comment: Do you get any errors? (What OS, browser?) And you can just copy the sources of the examples and paste them in files with the provided names. And should run fine on a local server.

Comment: @towr See the edit. I tried to copy HTML but it is executed instead! How can I copy html code?

Comment: I've put a zipped directory at http://wikisend.com/download/748756/angular.zip Which (for me) works as-is at `http://localhost/angular`. (I've added a `base href` so it works in a subdirectory, and added a link to the css in the `index.html`, which was missing)

Comment: @towr Tried and got lots of errors: http://pastie.org/8575190

Comment: You added an extra directory, so you have to adjust the `base href` in index.html to `<base href="/Testers/angular/">`

Comment: @towr Yes, thanks, that was the cause. Did that now and it works ... until I reload - `Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI` (for `http://localhost:8888/Testers/angular/Book/Moby`)

Comment: @towr Also `$route.current.scope.name` is not updated like in the demo

Comment: The 404 is correct, because that page doesn't exist on your server. What you could do is use `mod-rewrite` in apache to rewrite all `/Testers/angular/*` urls to go to `/Testers/angular/index.html` I'll have a look at the `scope` thing, hadn't noticed that.

Comment: Hmm, actually, `$route.current.scope.name =` isn't updated in the demo either (not when I look, anyway).

Comment: @towr Indeed, but it is updated here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route

Comment: @towr Also the reload does not work in the demo. I don't quite understand the need of pushstate in that example when simple fragments would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what I was looking for:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/

Perfect and functional!